Can I see the origin of light before it reaches the final point, so do I see the origin at the exact moment it is created?
Questioning the Perception of Light and Its Path
I have a question about the perception of light and its propagation. The main question is:
"Can I see the origin of light before it reaches the final point, so do I see the origin at the exact moment it is created?"
Let's imagine the following scenario: a flashlight (point A) is in one location, and the light is directed at an object (point B). I, the observer, am at point C, away from the direct path of the light beam. My question is whether, by observing the light as it travels, I could see the origin of the light at the exact moment it is created, even before the light reaches point B.
In other words, considering that light takes some time to travel the distance to point B, could I see the light propagating in "super slow motion," seeing the beam and the shadow forming behind the object as the light hits it, without the light actually hitting me directly? That is, would it be possible to observe the full path of the light, from its origin (in the flashlight) to its destination (on the object), without needing to wait for the light to directly hit point C?
This idea is related to the finite speed of light and how the travel time affects the perception of events. I still have doubts about the real behavior of light in this type of observation, and I would like to know if this has any physical basis or if it's a misunderstanding.


https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/13684/1316674

Por que fechou, é pergunta séria

The answer is in the above link.


In other words, considering that light takes some time to travel the distance to point B, could I see the light propagating in "super slow motion," seeing the beam and the shadow forming behind the object as the light hits it, without the light actually hitting me directly?

You don't really need point C at all actually. The useful notion of an "observer" or a "frame" is that it can be thought of as consisting of synchronized clocks, all moving together and each of them assigned to a specific spatial position that is fixed with respect to the frame's origin.
So, assuming you can synchronize clocks (that's a bit trickier than it sounds, as I'll mention later), just put them all along the beam's path from A to B, and have them record when a single "flash" of the beam passes them.
You can do the same thing for the formation of the shadow: since you can anticipate where the shadow will form, the clocks positioned in these locations can record when a certain spatial position became "dark" due to a shadow, etc. (or to be more precise, darker than the points surrounding the shadow, that the beam of light does illuminate).
So, after you've done all this, you can in principle go to your big database or wherever you store all this information, and reconstruct a position vs. time graph for the light beam, and also a similar graph for the shadow.
The upshot here is that it's very important to distinguish what a single observer will optically perceive in a situation, vs. what information can be reconstructed by having a "reference frame", like I've mentioned in the above. What a single observer optically perceives, indeed will require an analysis of how light from different points in space get to his particular observation point. This leads to all kinds of optical effects which are interesting, and sometimes related to effects that also a reference frame "observes" in the sense that was discussed previously.
For example the Penrose-Terrell effect is an optical effect that is a result of both Lorentz contraction, which is a frame related effect, and also a specifically optical phenomenon caused by how light is reflected from an extended object to a specific spatial point.
Now to go back to the tricky bit, about synchronizing clocks: it turns out that the straightforward way we define the synchronization of clocks is by assuming that the speed of light is isotropic (isotropic just means, independent of direction). This in turn implies we can only ever measure the two-way speed of light rather than the one-way speed of light. I don't think that's a "rabbit hole" you wanted to get into with this question, but if you do, there are quite a few posts about it already, so I recommend looking around and becoming more familiar with the issue first if you feel that it is of relevance to your question.

Another example is a streetlight pointing downwards and you see this streetlight at the bottom of the city when you are on the mountain, these lights are pointing towards the ground at the time they turn on, their objective is to reach the ground but the its light doesn't reach me, if it were in super slow motion I would see it rising at the exact moment and then touching the ground and only then would I be able to see it according to science, but I saw the moment the light rose and touched the ground.

The only things you see are due to light entering your eyes, that's obvious. If light has no way to reach your eyes, you see nothing, regardless of what physical processes are happening somewhere else. Luckily however, in science we measure things with instruments that in many respects are more accurate and more reliable than human eyes. This is how we study light and its properties, along with many other phenomena in nature.

This from MIT is perhaps as close to what you are thinking as you can get.

It is based on stroboscopic techniques. Femto-Photography: Visualizing Photons in Motion at a Trillion Frames Per Second. What you see gives a good idea of how light propagates in their setup. Light from a very short pulse spreads out, reflects off things, and arrives at the camera.
It is important to keep in mind that the camera does not capture light on the way to the objects. It captures light that has already reflected off the objects. They repeat the pulse over and over. Each time, the camera takes a picture with a very short exposure time. Each frame shows light from that instant.
